How can I use OAuth to create or use a IdentityUser instance in ASP.NET?
I have an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API with Identity set up. I have a React SPA that interacts with the ASP.NET Core backend. I want the only login way to be LinkedIn and not email/password, and it is not enough to just authenticate the user with LinkedIn, I need them to have a user in the database as well because fundamental functionality requires the user to be persisted in the database.
I've had a horrible time so far. I first tried Openiddict but due to lacking documentation how to set it up in the most basic way with a single Auth provider, I've had to give that up.
The current route I've taken so far is this:
Program.cs:
// ...
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
});

builder.Services
    .AddIdentityApiEndpoints<ApplicationUser>()
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddCookie("cookie")
    .AddOAuth("LinkedIn", options =>
    {
        options.SignInScheme = "cookie";
        options.ClientId = linkedInClientId;
        options.ClientSecret = linkedInClientSecret;
        options.AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization";
        options.TokenEndpoint = "https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken";
        options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/oauth/linkedin-cb");
        options.UserInformationEndpoint = "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/userinfo";
        // options.Scope.Add("liteprofile");
        options.Scope.Add("email");
        options.Scope.Add("profile");
        options.Scope.Add("openid");
        options.SaveTokens = true;

        options.Events = new OAuthEvents
        {
            OnCreatingTicket = async context =>
            {
                using var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, context.Options.UserInformationEndpoint);
                request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", context.AccessToken);

                using var response = await context.Backchannel.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, context.HttpContext.RequestAborted);
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                var user = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<JsonElement>();

                context.RunClaimActions(user);
            }
        };

        options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "sub");
        options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Name, "name");
        options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Email, "email");
    });
// ...

app.MapGet("/login", () =>
{
    return Results.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = new PathString("/") }, authenticationSchemes: ["LinkedIn"]);
});

This works as it sets a cookie, but I get no persisted user in the db, and it uses cookies while I really want JWT. I could not get it to work with JWT.
So as a last resort I'm asking here if anyone has any experience with using OAuth as a means to simply authenticate users in order to create an IdentityUser. Thank you.

A few things I think needs to be specified in the docs:

The OAuth CallbackPath field is not to specify which path to call as part of the callback procedure, it confusingly just lets you define what callback route ASP.NET uses internally to handle the OAuth process...
You have to create the JWT yourself unlike cookie
Creating the JWT for the SPA frontend needs to happen in the OAuth defined OAuthEvents Events option

That being said, here's my Program.cs that I've made working for LinkedIn OAuth used to only identity users, and then storing them as IdentityUser and creating a JWT for them:

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var config = builder.Configuration;

// make sure config fields are set
string linkedInClientId = config["OAuth:LinkedIn:ClientId"] ?? string.Empty, linkedInClientSecret = config["OAuth:LinkedIn:ClientSecret"] ?? string.Empty;
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(linkedInClientId) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(linkedInClientSecret))
{
    throw new Exception("OAuth:LinkedIn:ClientId and OAuth:LinkedIn:ClientSecret must be set in appsettings.json");
}

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
});

builder.Services
    .AddIdentityApiEndpoints<ApplicationUser>()
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(config["Jwt:Key"])),
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidIssuer = config["Jwt:Issuer"],
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudience = config["Jwt:Issuer"]
        };
    })
    .AddOAuth("LinkedIn", options =>
    {
        options.SignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
        options.ClientId = linkedInClientId;
        options.ClientSecret = linkedInClientSecret;
        options.AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization";
        options.TokenEndpoint = "https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken";
        options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/auth/linkedin-callback");
        options.UserInformationEndpoint = "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/userinfo";
        // options.Scope.Add("liteprofile");
        options.Scope.Add("email");
        options.Scope.Add("profile");
        options.Scope.Add("openid");
        options.SaveTokens = true;

        options.Events = new OAuthEvents
        {
            OnCreatingTicket = async context =>
            {
                using var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, context.Options.UserInformationEndpoint);
                request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", context.AccessToken);

                using var response = await context.Backchannel.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, context.HttpContext.RequestAborted);
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                var user = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<JsonElement>();

                context.RunClaimActions(user);
            },
            OnTicketReceived = async context =>
            {
                var userManager = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
                var signInManager = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>>();

                var email = context.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
                var user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);

                if (user == null)
                {
                    user = new ApplicationUser
                    {
                        UserName = email,
                        Email = email,
                        EmailConfirmed = true,
                        Name = context.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name)
                        // Add any other properties you want to set for new users
                    };
                    var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user);
                    if (!result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        throw new Exception($"Failed to create user: {string.Join(", ", result.Errors.Select(e => e.Description))}");
                    }
                }

                // this sets cookie for the user, which is not needed since we're creating our own JWT token anyways, but why not
                await signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);

                // Generate and set JWT token
                var token = GenerateJwtToken(user, userManager, config);

                // Redirect to your frontend with the token
                context.ReturnUri = $"http://localhost:3000/auth-callback?token={token}";
            }
        };

        options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "sub");
        options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Name, "name");
        options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Email, "email");
    });
// .AddLinkedIn(o => {
//     o.CallbackPath = "/auth/linkedin-callback";
//     o.ClientId = linkedInClientId;
//     o.ClientSecret = linkedInClientSecret;
//     // o.Scope.Add("profile");
//     // o.Scope.Add("email");
//     // o.Scope.Add("openid");
//     // o.Scope.Add("r_liteprofile");
//     // o.Scope.Add("r_emailaddress");
//     o.SaveTokens = true;
// });
builder.Services.AddControllers();

// Swagger
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
// https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8J3nuUegtL4
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(opt =>
{
    opt.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Description = "Please insert JWT with Bearer into field",
        Name = "Authorization",
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey
    });
    opt.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement {
   {
     new OpenApiSecurityScheme
     {
       Reference = new OpenApiReference
       {
         Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
         Id = "Bearer"
       }
      },
      new string[] { }
    }
  });
});

// Services
builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<AiApiService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IRoleService, RoleService>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
//if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
//{
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();
//}

// Uncomment to add Identity API endpoints, but we want only LinkedIn auth
//app.MapIdentityApi<ApplicationUser>();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseCors(builder => builder
    .AllowAnyOrigin()
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .AllowAnyHeader());

app.MapControllers();

// Auth
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapGet("/login", () =>
{
    return Results.Challenge(authenticationSchemes: ["LinkedIn"]);
});

// Helper method to generate JWT token
static string GenerateJwtToken(ApplicationUser user, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, IConfiguration config)
{
    var claims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.Id),
        new(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email, user.Email),
        new(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
    };

    var userRoles = userManager.GetRolesAsync(user).Result;
    foreach (var role in userRoles)
    {
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
    }

    var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(config["Jwt:Key"]));
    var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
    var expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(Convert.ToDouble(config["Jwt:ExpireDays"]));

    var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
        config["Jwt:Issuer"],
        config["Jwt:Audience"],
        claims,
        expires: expires,
        signingCredentials: creds
    );

    return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
}


// Migrate db
using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
    var dbContext = services.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
    dbContext.Database.Migrate();
}
// Seed roles
using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
    var roleService = services.GetRequiredService<IRoleService>();

    await roleService.SeedRolesAsync();
}

app.Run();


Hope this helps others avoid wasting as much time as I have making this simple OAuth scenario work with Identity and JWT, which I imagine is a very common use case so it's stupid that it's in MS ASP.NET documentation... but here it is.
